# What library is the error() function in?

Tags: c++

I try to use the error() function in my program, but it shows "Error: identifier "error" is undefined". Is there a library that I need to include? 
This is found from a book called "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++". The error() function will terminate the program with a system error message plus the string that is passed to error() as an argument.

```
if (x<=0) error("non-positive x"); 
if (y<=0) error("non-positive y");
int area1 = area(x,y);
```

> Really, the only question is what to do if we
>   find an error. Here, we have called a function error() which we assume
>   will do something sensible. In fact, in std_lib_facilities.h we supply
>   an error() function that by default terminates the program with a
>   system error message plus the string we passed as an argument to
>   error(). If you prefer to write out your own error message or take
>   other actions, you catch runtime_error (§5.6.2, §7.3, §7.8, §B.2.1).
>   This approach suffices for most student programs and is an example of
>   a style that can be used for more sophisticated error handling.

Comment: What is the `error()` function? Where did you read about it?

Comment: There is no standard `error` function. Do you mean [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror) or the symbol [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno), or the [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) function?

Comment: What do you expect `error()` to do? Throw an error, retrieve a message for an exception or an error code? Retrieve an error code for an exception or vice versa? Try searching the web for something that does it using "<purpose> c++ library".

Comment: I am doing self learning from a book called "Programming Principles And Practice Using C++". The error() function will terminate the program with a system error message plus the string passed as an argument to error().

Comment: Voted to reopen. It's quite clear what the question is asking.

Comment: Maybe the book have its own library with support functions? Have you checked for that?

Answer (score 6):

It is a user defined function. If you take a look at section 5.6.3 "Bad input", you can see, he defines it as:

```
void error (string s)

{
  throw runtime_error (s);
}
```

He redefines it further in the text to accept two arguments.

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid right now for not knowing that...

Answer (score 3):

In your book

> ### Support
>
> The book's support website, http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming, contains a variety of materials supporting the teaching and learning of programming using this book. The material is likely to be improved with time, but for starters, you can find:
>
> - Slides for lectures based on the book
> - An instructor's guide
> - **Header flies and implementations of libraries used in the book**
> - Code for examples in the book
> - Solutions to selected exercises
> - Potentially useful links
> - Errata Suggestions for improvements are always welcome.

And later at the end of first chapter:

> So, here is your first drill:
>
> 1. Go to Appendix C and follow the steps required to set up a project. Set up an empty, console C++ project called hello_ world.
>
> [...]
>
> How do you find std_lib_facilities.h? If you are in a course, ask your
>   instructor. If not, download it from our support site
>   http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely answer is https://linux.die.net/man/3/error, a GNU extension (and part of GNU's libc).

Answer (score 1):

The function `error()` is not a standard API call. I suspect that your book is either talking about a library that provides this function, or it includes a library of its own that implements this function.

For error handling in C++, you can use the `perror()` C API call, but the best solution is to use an exception-based object-oriented solution for the task.

Answer (score 0):

```
void error(std::string error_type)
{
    std::cout << error_type << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This is just saying the error and not stopping the program.

Comment: It is best usually to explain how your code will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use perror() instead of error().
you can find perror() function inside cstdio library
for example:

```
  int n;
 cin >> n;
  if(n<0) {
 perror("negative input is not allowed");
 }else {
     cout << sqrt(n);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, unfortunately.